# Circular dependency between resources: CognitoUserPool and environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I am getting an error when i try to use `Ref`: to `AWS::Cognito::UserPool` in lambda environment when the lambda is bound to events from `cognitoUserPool`

This is the error

`The CloudFormation template is invalid: Circular dependency between resources:`

Serverless code

```
functions:
  cognito:
    handler: src/lambdas.cognito
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          pool: General
          trigger: CustomMessage
      - cognitoUserPool:
          pool: General
          trigger: PostConfirmation
      - cognitoUserPool:
          pool: General
          trigger: PreSignUp
    environment:
      COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID:
        Ref: CognitoUserPoolGeneral

resources:
  Resources:
    CognitoIdentityPoolGeneral:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool
      Properties:
        IdentityPoolName: IdentityPool
        AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: false
        CognitoIdentityProviders:
          -
            ClientId:
              Ref: CognitoUserPoolGeneralWebClient
            ProviderName:
              Fn::GetAtt: [CognitoUserPoolGeneral,ProviderName]

    CognitoIdentityPoolGeneralRoleAttachments:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment
      Properties:
        IdentityPoolId:
          Ref: CognitoIdentityPoolGeneral
        Roles:
          authenticated:
            Fn::GetAtt: [CognitoIdentityPoolAuthRole,Arn]
          unauthenticated:
            Fn::GetAtt: [CognitoIdentityPoolUnAuthRole,Arn]


    CognitoIdentityPoolAuthRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: CognitoIdentityAuth
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            -
              Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Federated: cognito-identity.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
              Condition:
                StringEquals:
                  cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud:
                    Ref: CognitoIdentityPoolGeneral
                ForAnyValue:StringLike:
                  cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr: authenticated



    CognitoIdentityPoolUnAuthRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: CognitoIdentityUnAuth
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            -
              Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Federated: cognito-identity.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
              Condition:
                StringEquals:
                  cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud:
                    Ref: CognitoIdentityPoolGeneral
                ForAnyValue:StringLike:
                  cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr: unauthenticated


    CognitoUserPoolGeneral:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: general
        AutoVerifiedAttributes: [ email ]
        AliasAttributes: [ email ]
        Policies:
          PasswordPolicy:
            MinimumLength: 6
            RequireLowercase: false
            RequireNumbers: false
            RequireSymbols: false
            RequireUppercase: false
        Schema:
          - AttributeDataType: String
            Name: landingWebSite
            DeveloperOnlyAttribute: false
            Mutable: true
            Required: false
          - AttributeDataType: String
            Name: userAgentLocale
            DeveloperOnlyAttribute: false
            Mutable: true
            Required: false

    CognitoUserPoolGeneralWebClient:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
      Properties:
        ClientName: web
        GenerateSecret: false
        RefreshTokenValidity: 30
        UserPoolId:
          Ref: CognitoUserPoolGeneral
```

Comment: When you use the [Cognito User Pool event](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cognito-user-pool/), Serverless generates the `LambdaConfig` property on the named pool, sets up a `Fn::GetAtt` to the `<Function>.Arn` attribute, thus creating the circular reference.

Comment: Yes i know why i get circular dep, but my question is can this be solved? because as i know environment can be set after lambda is created.

Comment: How did you get around the role permission for lambda calling the pool?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I need to access the user pool client ID in some of my HTTP handlers (to be able to call functions on the user pool) and if I stick it in an environment variable I get a circular dependency. Did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

By removing the following section:

```
  COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID:
    Ref: CognitoUserPoolGeneral
```

Your deployment should work without an issue. 
To get the User Pool properties - the User Pool ID can be found in the event object (other properties are just a matter of querying).

Comment: Any idea how to handle the iam role section for the lambda?

Comment: yes you can find the pool from the event, and how about securing your lambda from NOT accessing other pool resources that it shouldn't be accessing?

so when yo uwant to define IAM roles you need the ARN and that creates circular dependency. :/